# chmod android file system from script

Tags: android, shell, chmod

I'm using an Android-x86 vm running in vmware fusion for some testing purposes. I am pushing files to it via `adb push`, however, every time I uninstall and reinstall the app, I have to execute the following:

```
adb shell
su
chmod 777 /my/path
exit
exit
```

I need to be able to script out this entire process but I'm not sure how I can manage the chmod process via some sort of script. I tried doing something like

```
adb shell am chmod 777 /my/path
```

But that doesn't work. I thought it would because I can do

```
adb shell am start ...
```

I also tried:

```
adb shell "su && chmod 777 /my/path && exit && exit"
```

which actually works, but doesn't exit the shell process. So any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass commands to adb shell, as you mentioned, though it works better if you surround the command in quotes.

Likewise, you can pass commands to the 'su' command using the -c argument. Add all of this together and it should do what you want in a nice one-liner!

```
adb shell "su -c 'chmod 777 /my/path'"
```